# Nuxt.js - How to use component inside layout?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

So I started playing around with Nuxt.js. 
I want to modify the default layout file to have a header and a footer.
For that I want to create a Header and a Footer component and place the page content tag (`<nuxt/>`) between them. However nothing happens.

Here is my default.vue layout file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <header/>
    <nuxt/>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "~/components/Header.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Header
  }
};
</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

Here is my Header.vue component file:

```
<template>
<div>
<h1>Header</h1>
   <div class="links">
          <nuxt-link to="/" class="button--grey">Home</nuxt-link>
          <nuxt-link to="/about" class="button--grey">About</nuxt-link>
      </div>
</div>
</template>

<style>
.links {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
</style>
```

Is there something wrong with this? Can I use components inside layouts files in the first place? Do I have to register newly created components separately somewhere else?

Sadly, there isn't much information specifically about this. How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `nothing happend` means? no header and footer rendered out? just a blank page? any error in the browser console? or nodejs console?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try changing `<header />` to  `<Header />`. (as the component you have defined for the view is Header with a capital H.)

> **Capitalization is important.** In this case, because `header` is an [existing element tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Content_sectioning), Vue will just render an empty tag without complaining.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use reserved HTML tags for component names. It includes footer, header etc. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) full list of reserved tag names.

So you need to rename your component to something different, for example my-header

Comment: This seems not to be the case anymore. Just created a "Footer" component just fine

Comment: @brpaz Footer != footer. It's still a case